# Remove xml header using QRegexp from String in Qt

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I want to remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` from string in Qt for this I wrote code:

```
outputText.replace(QRegExp("<\?xml.*?\?>"),""); where outputText is QString.
```

But xml header was not removed even I tried with regular expression `"\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>"` too for this xml heaader but this regex is not working so please let me know valid regular expression which will remove above mentioned xml header from the string.

Comment: did you try this `"<\\?xml(.+?)\\?>"`?

Comment: No, it is not working (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
QRegExp("\\<\\?xml[^(\\?\\>)]*\\?\\>");
```

You will have to escape `>`, `<`, `?` with `\`, which itself needs to be escaped by `\` for being a C/C++ string.

With this actually you match everything starting with `<?xml` up to the next `?>`.